# Difference between #id and div#id

Tags: html, css

I am new to css. Can someone help me in differentiating "#test" and "div#test"?

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
  <div>
    <span>Some stuff here..</span>
  </div>
  <div id="test">
    <span>This is my data</span>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: id is represented with #, where id is a unique identifier . you can make a css selector by using id.

Comment: I would recommend you read up on selectors and their specificity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You really ought not to qualify an ID with a tagname per the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ar/docs/CSS/Writing_Efficient_CSS), as follows:

> Don’t qualify ID rules with tag names or classes
>
> If a rule has an ID
>   selector as its key selector, don’t add the tag name to the rule.
>   Since IDs are unique, adding a tag name would slow down the matching
>   process needlessly

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is the specifity weight changes.

Doing #id is less specific than div#id

This means that your div#id rules are used because it has a higher specifity value

```
div#id {background: #000} 
#id {background: #fff}
```

The background of the div with that id will be black, even if another rule is selected afterwards

Answer (score 1):

`#test` will take the element with the id **test** while `div#test` will only take the **div** with an id named **test**.
This doesn't make a great difference since ids have to be unique.

This kind of info is pretty easy to find, you may want to take a look at [W3schools documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp)

Answer (score 1):

#id & div#id differs only when applying styles to that element.

Browser calculates the most relevant element by calculating specificity.

specificity calculate rules are in the follwing link
https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/cascade.html#specificity

#id will be 0100
and div#id will be 0103

So what does the number means if you write

```
div#id {
  background: green;
}

#id {
  background: red;
}
```

the color of box will be green

reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 0):

**The #id** is Selects the element with id="firstname". It is one kind of CSS Selectors.

Check all CSS Selectors at https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

There is a minor difference.

**When you use div#id** it will only apply to #id that are attached to a div. Otherwise the rule is ignored.

Hope it helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you use div#id it will only apply to #id that is attached to a div.
Specificity of div#id is more than that of #div.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<style>
    div#test {
    background: green;
}
inspector-stylesheet:1
#test {
    background: red;
}
</style>
<body><div>
    <span>Some stuff here..</span>
  </div>
  <div id="test">
    <span>This is my data</span>
  </div></body>
<span id="test">This is my data</span>
</html>
```

Basically id's are unique but to show how the element is specific when used with combination div#id if there are two different elements with test for two different elements then the stronger would be the specified element like div#id

Answer (score 0):

As you can see below, `div#test` is a selector only for divs with the id `test`. `#test` will select every element with the id `test`.

However, since you should never use an id multiple times, this should not be a problem. `div#test` will just slow down the matching in the DOM so you shouldn't use it.

Just to be clear: if you chain elements and ids, you are more specific. This means, these specifications will always override less specific ones.

```css
div#test{color:green}
#test{color:red}
```

The color will be green.

---

If you meant `div #test`, that's for chaining through the DOM tree.

```css
div#test{ float:right}
#test{color:green}
div #test{margin-left:60px}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
  <div>
    <span>Some stuff here..</span>
  </div>
  <div id="test">
    <span>This is my data</span>
  </div>
  <span id="test">no data</span>
  <div>
    <span id="test">heres data</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      <span id="test">heres data aswell</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The specificity is different (`div#test` one is higher) and `div#test` applies to only a div, not other tags.

`div#test` specificity is 0101

`#test` specificity is 0100

[Specificity Calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/)